# How to open 10 browsers with jmeter

Tags: performance, selenium, jmeter, performance-testing

I'm using jmeter for performance testing.I used Selenium for functional testing.I want to test 10 users access same login page at same time.I can do that with jmeter. I want to open 10 browsers at same time(like selenium )and display on screen,can I do that using jmeter??Is there any plugin  that I can use for this??

Answer (score 2):

Curious...what scenario are you testing that needs ten browsers open on the same machine at once?

Jmeter can't do this, as Jmeter itself is the emulated browser.  You could open ten JMeter instances, but that would give you the same effect as having ten threads in a single script.

Now, if you need ten browsers on ten different machines, then Jmeter CAN do this using Remote Mode.

Comment: thanxx for response.I'm trying load testing now,So is there any other tool that can use to open ten browsers in same machine??

Comment: Still curious...what scenario are you trying to test?? I would check out this list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools.

Comment: testPartner would launch ten browsers at once

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Selenium Plugin with JMeter. This will open physical browsers on your machine and make recordings (start and stop at your define timers).

Refer to guidelines from Blazemeter, here: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler

I have tested with the later version of JMeter 3.0 and it worked fine. Limitation was that I had to use older version of FF.

Note the recommendation is to roughly have more cores than the number of browsers in the load injector machine.

With JMeter your response times will balloon as/if your load injector gets bottlenecked, if you have too many browsers running on the injector. Ensure your recorded timings are comparable to your manual checks - if you have timers in wrong places, it won't be accurate either.

If you are after client side performance tests, I'd recommend other tools like webpagetest. JMeter with selenium is not the best for client side performance tests.

Answer (score 1):

BadBoy may be useful for you here:
http://www.badboy.com.au/

It's free software that records your actions, which you can then export to a jmx file to run as a test script.

Comment: It can...you'd need to specify the target window as _blank

Answer (score 1):

Hi @123Ex have a look at TurboSelenium https://butlerthing.io/products#demovideo
We can run multiple fully headed browsers on one machine. 
This tool is not free though.

Answer (score 1):

You can of course use Jmeter's `Selenium/WebDriver support` plugin to open N instances of browser on your system. But, be careful about the N number. Too many instances will freeze your system itself. Also, some of the supported driver config, like the `jp@gc - Chrome Driver Config` supports headless option; that may help you to increase the N to some extent. But, after a point, even headless browser wont help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium if you want to want to open 10 browsers concurrently. If you are just trying to simulate 10 user loging in concurrently, use JMeter (No Browsers Necessary).